# CheckboxGroupInput not rendering after save in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, admin-on-rest

I'm new to react and react-admin and I have a problem with CheckboxGroupInput or with any input of array type.

I have a form, this is the code:

```
export const MoviesCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="name" validate={[required()]} />
            <TextInput source="actors" validate={[required()]} />
            <TextInput source="year" validate={[required()]} />
            <CheckboxGroupInput source="gender" validate={[required()]} choices={[
                { id: 'Action', name: 'Action' },
                { id: 'Adventure', name: 'Adventure' },
                { id: 'Animation', name: 'Animation' },
                { id: 'Biography', name: 'Biography' },
            ]} />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

So when I want to create a new item, after I hit the save button I got this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I think the problem is that the response from REST API is not correctly returned but I don't know what is the correct format for that. These are the responses that I tried to returned from REST API but nothing works:

1.

```
{id: 42, name: "test", year: "1234", actors: "asd", gender: "Adventure,Animation"}
```

2.

```
{id: 43, name: "Black Friday", year: "1234", actors: "asd", gender: ["Animation", "Adventure"]}
```

3.

```
{id: 43, name: "Black Friday", year: "1234", actors: "asd", gender: [{id: "Adventure", name: "Adventure"}, {id: "Animation", name: "Animation"}]}
```

4.

```
{id: 43, name: "Black Friday", year: "1234", actors: "asd", gender: {id: "Animation", name: "Animation"}}
```

I have the same problem with ArrayInput or AutocompleteArrayInput...

Can anyone help me with this problem and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, according to the description, data option 2 (array of strings) should work.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to let the user choose multiple values among a list of possible values by showing them all,`<CheckboxGroupInput>` is the right component. Set the `choices` attribute to determine the options (with `id`, `name` tuples):

[Description](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Inputs.md#checkboxgroupinput)

```
<CheckboxGroupInput source="category" choices={[
    { id: 'programming', name: 'Programming' },
    { id: 'lifestyle', name: 'Lifestyle' },
    { id: 'photography', name: 'Photography' },
]} />
```

So,the response from REST API should be like:option 3

```
{id: 43, name: "Black Friday", year: "1234", actors: "asd", gender: [{id: "Adventure", name: "Adventure"}, {id: "Animation", name: "Animation"}]}
```